# cakephp displaying associated model data

Tags: cakephp, associations, models

i really need help with this for my school project.
i am new to cakephp and trying to develop a school management application.i have a students table with admission number and a guarduins table with a foreign key pointing to admission number in the students table.
i need to associate the two models via the admission number and from the studentscontroller  be able to access a particular students guardian details.can anyone please point me in the right direction.
thanks in advance.
am using version 2.5

Answer (score 1):

> "can anyone please point me in the right direction"

Sure.  The online [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) is what you're looking for.  It has everything you'll need to know, is searchable, and has a lot of great examples.